# Using array elements for creating new arrays?

Tags: javascript

I need some help for a problem.I have array like this

```
var teams= ["real madrid","manchester united","real madrid","paris saint german"...]
```

.And I need to create arrays for holding informations about each teams in this array like

```
var real madrid = [ goals:0,wins:0,loses:0]
```

I tried this code

```
for(i=0;i<teams.length;i++)[
var teams[i].toString() = [goals:0,wins:0,loses:0];
]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: js object is like `{ goals:0,wins:0,loses:0 }` not  in `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably come up with some combination of arrays to hold this if you really want to, but you probably just want some objects like this:

```
var teams= ["real madrid","manchester united","real madrid","paris saint german"],
    stats = {}, i, currentTeam;

for(i=0;i<teams.length;i++) {
  currentTeam = teams[i];
  stats[currentTeam] = {goals: 0, wins: 0, losses: 0};
}
```

Then you will be able to "index" your stats like this:
stats['real madrid'].goals
stats['manchester united'].losses
etc, etc